# Entity Framework 6 access and decorate RelationShip tables using model first

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 with model first approach.

Is there a way to decorate relationship tables with extra field and gain access to them?

I am looking for a way to implement tracking history.

Comment: Are you asking is it possible to access connecting table in a many to many relationship? Yes, just explicitly declare the table.https://adrianscorner.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/designing-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-fields-using-entity-framework/

Comment: Steve - is it possible to do this when using "model first" approach?

Comment: Yes, just add an extra field to the model.

Comment: But Steve - I don't see Entity tables for relationship tables... :/

Comment: Are you doing code first or database first with an EDMX? I thought it was latter in which case you add extra field to the database mode.

Comment: I am doing model first. At this point I have turned away from many to many relationships and am creating relationship tables manualy